# Android Studio : execution failed for task app:processDebugResources

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image]

I need help. I have just installed Android Studio.
After creating a project I face this problem.

Comment: that surely is too less information, also try embedding the error message as text so people can find it actually

Answer (score 0):

Try clean Build once. Add some gradle logs if you have any for more info